# Class definition which could approve argument - with object and constructor

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

I have to create class definiton which could approve argument that the object has already existed at the moment when constructor was inducted.

I have no idea how to explain this, I've tried somethin like this but it's propably wrong:

```
public class B {

  int obj;

  public B() {  

  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    B object = new B();
    System.out.println(object)

    }
}
```

Code which i wrote, from the first excercise is:

```
public class Bulb {

static int a;

public Bulb(int ab) {
    a = ab;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Bulb object = new Bulb(a);
    System.out.println(object);

}
```

And it's with one parameter constructor.

Comment: Not sure if you mean the Singleton pattern? http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you said "approve argument that the object has already existed"; the approve argument part is throwing me off. I also though of the singleton pattern, like barrowc said, but please clarify.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid Singleton? Static methods maybe, but how?

Comment: @Teeg i think it's accord to previous excercise where I had to create class without any constructor and then create object of this class. Of course, the object was created. After the question was about to explain how it happened (default constructor). In the second part of this excercise I had to expend class with one parameter and try to compile it. The second excercise (from question): prove the thesis that object has existed when constructor was inducted. I think it may be sth with static method becouse i've not heard about Singleton at lessons.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that in your second exercise, you have to create a new class that has a member variable (such as your `int obj`). Am I correct that your constructor, must accept one parameter that will set the value of your `obj`?

Comment: @Taag question eddited (excercise one). Now I have to write second class which agree with thesis that this object, in this case Bulb, has existed before constructor was inducted.

Comment: If you just have to prove that an instance of the class was created before, you could create a static field (like 'a' in the second code) and use it as a counter. Each time the constructor is called, you add 1 to that counter. If the counter is more than 1, then the constructor was called before, so a object of that class was created before. Is this what you have to do?

Comment: @Fastkowy Ok so you're learning about inheritance and polymorphism, it sounds like, correct? You need to extend the `Bulb` class, and prove that the Bulb constructor is invoked BEFORE the sub class constructor?

Comment: @Teeg Oh yes, that makes more sense

Comment: @Teeg Yes, i think you'r right. And im beginner so Singleton... is kind of magic for me right now :)

Comment: @Fastkowy Singleton is pretty easy stuff, but you'll learn about that later one. Glad that was the right answer; I was starting to run out of ideas.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our long comment thread, it sounds like we've determined that what you're doing is learning about inheritance and polymorphsim. The B class you specified has to inherit from Bulb, and you must prove that Bulb's constructor is invoked first BEFORE B's constructor. I'm not certain if there's any better way than to use log outputs. Your code nearly has everything you need, except for the extension, and logger messages. You can do both like so:

```
public class Bulb{
    int ab;
    public Bulb(int ab){
        this.ab = ab;
        System.out.println("Bulb constructor is invoked");
    }

    // The rest of your Bulb class
}
```

And in the B class, which extends Bulb:

```
public class B extends Bulb{
    public B(int ab){
        // Call the super constructor, which in this case is the Bulb constructor
        super(ab);
        System.out.println("B constructor is invoked");
    }
    // The rest of your B class
}
```

Does that make sense?

Edit:
I forgot to mention: In Java, when you have an inheritance structure, the constructors are always called from top to bottom. Meaning, the top most class in your hierarchy is called first (in this case, that would be Bulb), and trickles down to the bottom (your B class, for example).